# tensorflow: how to use tf.nn.leaky_relu with alpha as activation_fn for tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected?

Tags: tensorflow

The default `activation_fn` for [tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/fully_connected) is `tf.nn.relu`.

If I want to change the `activation_fn` for a certain fully connected layer to `tf.nn.tanh` then I can call it as: `tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs, num_outputs, activation_fn=tf.nn.tanh)`

Now if I want to use `tf.nn.leaky_relu` with `alpha=0.01`, I can't do that. I can only use `tf.nn.leaky_relu` with the default value of `alpha`.

Is there any elegant way to do that ? Or should I make `activation_fn=None` and then manually call `tf.nn.leaky_relu` after that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just define a function based on `leaky_relu`.

For example you could use `activation_fn=lambda x: tf.nn.leaky_relu(x, alpha=0.01)`.

This is the same as `def lrelu_01(x): return tf.nn.leaky_relu(x, alpha=0.01)` and then passing `activation_fn=lrelu_01`.